# Fetch albums not working When Upgrade IOS Facebook SDK From 2.0 to 3.8

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I used to allow the users of my IOS app to choose the photos from their Facebook account.its working fine in Facebook old version through Graph API with the following code

```
    if(isFbPhotoRequest)
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

When i upgrade to new Facebook SDK.I do this by querying for the album then by searching through those albums. The album query does not works.i can achieved through the old version of Facebook SDK 2.0 but not new Facebook SDK 3.8

here is the code i use to make a call to get albums

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if(error) {

                          }

                          NSArray* collection = (NSArray*)[result data];
                          NSLog(@"You have %d albums", [collection count]);


                      }];
```

this code always return  0 albums.Is there a way to get rid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get albums you need to set "user data permission". Once you will set permission, "/me/albums" will give you array of Album objects.

You can do this using following code :-

```
         [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_photos"] allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error) {

                                  }

                              }];
    }];
```